# line break tag in specific situation html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Tooltip only Text
        $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
                // Hover over code
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                .text(title)
                .appendTo('body')
                .fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
                // Hover out code
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                $('.tooltip').remove();
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
                var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
                var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
                $('.tooltip')
                .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
        });
    });
```

its making image titles appear very nice, but I cant find a way to put a line break in there.

I have tried `<br> </br> <br/> &#32 &#013 n/` nothing worked

Comment: either try and .append('<br />'); or style your `p` to have display: block; and some margin-bottom:10px; etc

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: `n/`? Do you mean `\n`?

Comment: @ericosg the p tags are block level elements already.

Comment: indeed, i set the wrong tag as an example ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert html use `.html()` instead of `.text()`